# iOS PhoneGap 1.7.0 + Barcode Scanning Plugin issue

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins

Has anyone managed to get the BarcodeScanning plugin for PhoneGap to work on PhoneGap 1.7.0?

Barcode Scanning plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

The issues is that the plugin is not getting set when its added..

I get the following when I call "alert(window.plugins.barcodeScanner);"

"undefined"

I am trying to isolate the point where the plugin is failing to get added and will update the question once I know more..

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help...

---

Updated answer below:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK so after a bit of poking around and using the twitter PhoneGap plugin as an example I managed to get it working!!

I used this as a basis for my approach because the lovely people at twitter updated their plugin to work with PhoneGap 1.7.0 thank god!!

**Twitter PhoneGap Plugin:** https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/Twitter/js/TwitterPlugin.js

**Here is the updated barcodescanner.js code:**

```
var BarcodeScanner = function(){};

BarcodeScanner.prototype.isBarcodeScannerAvailable = function(response){
    cordova.exec(response, null, "BarcodeScannerPlugin", "isBarcodeScannerAvailable", []);
};

BarcodeScanner.prototype.isBarcodeScannerSetup = function(response){
    cordova.exec(response, null, "BarcodeScannerPlugin", "isBarcodeScannerSetup", []);
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
BarcodeScanner.Encode = {
TEXT_TYPE:     "TEXT_TYPE",
EMAIL_TYPE:    "EMAIL_TYPE",
PHONE_TYPE:    "PHONE_TYPE",
SMS_TYPE:      "SMS_TYPE",
CONTACT_TYPE:  "CONTACT_TYPE",
LOCATION_TYPE: "LOCATION_TYPE"
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
BarcodeScanner.prototype.scan = function(success, fail, options) {
    function successWrapper(result) {
        result.cancelled = (result.cancelled == 1)
        success.call(null, result)
    }

    if (!fail) { fail = function() {}}

    if (typeof fail != "function")  {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: failure parameter not a function")
        return
    }

    if (typeof success != "function") {
        fail("success callback parameter must be a function")
        return
    }

    if ( null == options ) 
        options = []

        return PhoneGap.exec(successWrapper, fail, "com.cordova.barcodeScanner", "scan", options)
        }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
BarcodeScanner.prototype.encode = function(type, data, success, fail, options) {
    if (!fail) { fail = function() {}}

    if (typeof fail != "function")  {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: failure parameter not a function")
        return
    }

    if (typeof success != "function") {
        fail("success callback parameter must be a function")
        return
    }

    return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "com.cordova.barcodeScanner", "encode", [{type: type, data: data, options: options}])
}

cordova.addConstructor(function() {

                       /* shim to work in 1.5 and 1.6  */
                       if (!window.Cordova) {
                       window.Cordova = cordova;
                       };


                       if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
                       window.plugins.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
                       });
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the new name: com.cordova.barcodeScanner.   How did you find this out?  <br> I changed it in Cordova.plist and at least it created the scanner object ok.  Note that the 21 hour old  file  still referenced org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner/barcodescanner.js.

Comment: @damien murphy - thanks mate, finally after 3 days of hair pulling it works...;)

Answer (score 11):

Excellent,

The plugin now works again. 

One issue is the documentation for the plugin still says the key in `Cordova.plist` should be `org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner` but obvious thing now it should be `com.cordova.barcodeScanner`.

Answer (score 3):

i just added barcodescanner to cordova 2.3 - it's quite simple

after copying the necessary files you only need to add the following line to config.xml

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone:
https://github.com/zeroasterisk/PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Example-iOS

Specifically:

Installed the plugin (in a handful of paths) but kept the one which worked. Implemented a basic JS scanner code to demonstrate functionality: auto-runs on load, auto-reloads on error, alerts on success/failure/cancel.

NOTE: the comments on the barcodescanner.js and index.js, both mention my customization of the define/require object paths. I could not get the demo/example paths to work, after several permutations.