# Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner' not found for ios Barcode Scanner Plugin in Cordova 2.0

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am trying to scan the barcode in the current project for ios. For that i used the Phone Gap plugin. I followed the link to add the files properly: [Barcode Link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner)

I added the barcodescanner.js file inside www folder of my project. But when i am pressing the button to scan the barcode in ipad 2, it is giving the below error:

```
  ERROR: Plugin 
'org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. 
Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist
```

It seems it is not getting the proper path of the **barcodescanner.js** file. I added the path in the index.html file also properly.

Can anyone please help??

Comment: i think u should update the calling mechanism from ur js to the plugin.

Comment: What do you mean by calling mechanism??

Comment: I added the key value pairs in the corodova.plist file..key as org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner and value as CDVBarcodeScanner

Comment: cordova.[exec](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS) call in js,

Comment: try these things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450259/ios-phonegap-1-7-0-barcode-scanning-plugin-issue. I have the same problem. It didn't help me but it might help you.

Comment: @dan i checked the above link and tried previously also..but it did not help me..

Answer (score 3):

Arindam,

I got it working now. What I did

1. Change the Key in the Cordova.plist as they did in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450259/ios-phonegap-1-7-0-barcode-scanning-plugin-issue)
2. Change the code of the barcodescanner.js as the did in the same link as above
3. Added the .cpp , .h and .mm files not only to the Folder in my workspace directory, but also added them to my xcode project:

> Right Click on "Plugins" -> Add Files To *projectname* -> Select the .cpp , .h and .mm file from my Plugins folder in the project Directory -> Set "Create Folder references for any added folders" and "add to Target *projectname*" -> Click "Add"

After adding the files to my project, the scanner worked.

hope that also solves it for you. I`m using Cordova 1.8.1 tho.

Comment: you mentioned: Added the .cpp , .h and .mm files not only to the Folder in my workspace directory, but also added them to my xcode project. What is this mean. I added those files in plugins as you told..but still it is not working.

Comment: do i have to add the js file also inside plugins folder??

Comment: I mean: I first added these files in my "Plugins" Folder in the File System Working Directory. They weren´t shown anywhere in Xcode tho (There is also a Plugins Folder in Xcode, which was empty in my case). So I added (you could also say: imported) them as described above to the Xcode Project.

Comment: If you only have it in Xcode, try to copy the files also to the filesystem Folder.

Comment: Tried adding them to xCode, and now the .mm file is giving me a compile error.